# What is the intuition behind contours and their geometric properties

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, contour-integration

What is the the intuition behind contours? Can someone explain whar are contours, their geometric properties in simple manner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contours as in contour integration?  They are curves in the complex plane (with enough smoothness properties that we can integrate over them, but the basic intuition is of a curve that you might draw with a pencil).  They have a starting point, an ending point, and a direction (from the start to the end).  In the case of a closed contour, the ending point is the same as the starting point.